# google drive api и авторизация

Tags: php, google-api

Доброго времени. Вместо засорения собственного сервера файлами и картинками, хочу засорять google drive. Для этого использую соответствующее api. Код для авторизации:

```
include "Google/autoload.php";

session_start();

$testFile = "file.jpg";

$client_id = 'myid.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'mysecret';
$redirect_uri = 'myurl/test.php';


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
   unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
   $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
   $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
   $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
   if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
       unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
   }
} 
else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  echo '<a href="'.$authUrl.'">Давайте авторизуемся в 100500 раз</a>';
}
```

Дальнейший код посвящен оперированию файлами и каталогами на google drive, всё вполне рабочее, но есть один вопрос: есть ли нативные средства для того, чтобы избежать ежечасных увлекательных переходов пользователем по ссылке авторизации и обратно? На просторах интернета нашел некоторые методы, использующие cURL, но не хотелось бы пользоваться ими, т.к. в таком случае зачем вообще google api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему примерно так (стоит добавить проверок):

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
//$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (file_exists("token.txt")){
$refreshToken = file_get_contents("token.txt");
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
}
else $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
file_put_contents("token.txt",$refreshToken);
}
```

Главным образом на решение повлияла строка `$client->setAccessType("offline");`, которую я упустил при чтении документации oauth2.